# singly embedded sum and product signs

Tags: fonts, symbols

I deal with a lot of double sums / double products. I would like to be able to massage TeX into producing something like this:

[image]

(that was made with the gimp)
... and a product in product symbol as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have a look at the section **Joining and overlapping existing symbols** in manual of [Comprehensive Symbol List](http://mirror.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\SUM{\mathop{%
  \ooalign{%
    \hfil$\displaystyle\sum$\cr
    \hfil$\textstyle\sum$\cr}}}

\[
  \SUM A_i
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

For what it is worth, Unicode defines

> ⅀ U+2140 DOUBLE-STRUCK N-ARY SUMMATION

If you are able to use [`unicode-math`](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) (with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX) and appropriate math fonts, you can access that symbol with `\mathbb{\sum}`.

STIX/XITS Math gives [image: stix double-struck sum] and Cambria Math gives [image: cambria double-struck sum].